# Sequelize findAndCountAll returns wrong count when association models included

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have models like picture below:

[image]

and the relations are defined as :

```
Level.hasMany(DoctorSpecializtion);
DoctorSpecializtion.belongsTo(Level);

DoctorSpecializtion.belongsTo(Specialization)
Doctor.hasMany(DoctorSpecializtion)
DoctorSpecializtion.belongsTo(Doctor)

Service.belongsToMany(Doctor, { through: DoctorService })
Doctor.belongsToMany(Service, { through: DoctorService })
Service.hasMany(DoctorService)
DoctorService.belongsTo(Service)
Doctor.hasMany(DoctorService)
DoctorService.belongsTo(Doctor)
```

now when i include  DoctorService or DoctorSpecializtion, find and count all returns wrong number.
I also tried separete:true

```
     include: [
                        {
                             separate: true,
                           
                            model: DoctorSpecializtion,
                            

                            attributes: ['id'],
                            where: { specializationId: { [Op.or]: value } },
                            include: [
                                {
                                    model: Specialization,
                                    attributes: ['title', 'slug'],
                                },
                                {
                                    model: Level,
                                    attributes: ['title', 'slug'],
                                },
                            ],
                        },
                    ],
```

but when i use seperate true the filting part which is

```
 where: { specializationId: { [Op.or]: value } },
```

it doest return my required result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i fixed this by removing seperate:true from my queries and added this query to my findAndCountAll query

```
 distinct: true,
col: 'Doctor.id',
```